# xslt 1.0 yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Tags: objective-c, date, xslt, nstimezone

I'm using xslt 1.0 and trying to convert my date from yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Input sample
`<StartDate>2014-07-2217:18:15</StartDate>`

Required output format `<startDate>2014-07-22T17:18:15.899+12:00</startDate>` in NZST timezone

I tried with sample as in http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/Tips/JavaInXslt without success as I'm getting the error that "The function 'sdf:new' was not defined". Also looked at EXSLT extensions for processing dates and times, but EXSLT don't have the function for timezone.

Kindly advice on how can I convert date from yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ other than using the concat "+12:00" to the end of startDate value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to do something like this with `NSTimeZone` (which you included as a tag) and `NSDateFormatter`. But since your question says you want to use XSLT, you seem to be ruling that out.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I convert date from yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss to
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ other than using the concat "+12:00" to the
>   end of startDate value?

There is no other way*. XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates; your data is a meaningless text string, and needs to be manipulated as such.

--
(*) Unless you create your own way by extending your processor capabilities with a user-defined function, as you have tried. But that 's a different question - and IMHO a solution using string functions is trivial and satisfactory.

Comment: The other issue is also regarding the daylight saving, when daylight saving starts it is +12:00 but when day light saving ends it is +13:00. Daylight saving ends at the last Sunday of September(+13:00)

Comment: @user3756530 As you say, it's another issue. And it cannot be solved satisfactorily using XSLT alone, because DST start and end points tend to fluctuate. Specifically in [New Zealand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_New_Zealand), dates before September 2007 need to be treated differently than dates after (for example). If you want to do this correctly, use an external function or a web service to access the [timezone database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA_time_zone_database).